# Can a VPN service read Telegram messages plaintext?

Tags: vpn, telegram

I need to use a remote VPN for work and I want to use the Telegram desktop application on my PC while connected on the VPN.

I would like to know whether the owners of the VPN service will be able to read Telegram messages in plaintext or not.

Thanks

Comment: Why do you think a VPN could? This is an odd assumption to make. Is your question "can one encryption service decrypt another encryption service's encryption?" just because they are both encrypted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I would like to know whether the owners of the VPN service will be able to read Telegram messages in plaintext or not.

**No one** is able to see your telegram chats other than yourself & the recipient. Even telegram engineers & on-site intruders of the cloud storage servers are not able to take a peek if they wanted to. These chats are heavily encrypted and the encryption keys are stored in several data centers in different jurisdictions, based on [Telegram's Privacy Policy](https://telegram.org/privacy)

The entire message is not sent in plaintext. This can be covered here,[Telegram's MTProto documentation.](https://core.telegram.org/mtproto)

If you are afraid of storing your data on their cloud infrastructure, you can opt for `secret chats` where telegram provide end-to-end encryption where encryption & decryption is based on 2 clients only, no servers are part of this transaction.

To summarize, encrypted data is **stored** on the server end, encrypted data is being **transported**, decryption happens on your end **only**!

Comment: What you stated is correct *IF AND ONLY IF* you use a Secure chat in Telegram. AFAIK, normal chat is not encrypted.

Comment: All Telegram chats use encryption, Secret Chats has an ADDITIONAL layer. It's in their FAQ :)